# Redirection to .aspx external link url with form POST, from Angular 8/10 not working in iPhone(Safari browsers)

Tags: javascript, angular, iis-7, payment-gateway, form-submit

Dears,
My problem statement is that-"
I'. trying to perform FORM SUBMIT from Angular 10 application, to an external ".aspx" endpoint.
Everything is working fine in all browsers GoogleChrome, Mozilla, Edge and MacBook (Chrome).

Issue is coming in iPhone (chrome/safari) and MacBook Safari browser, where during redirection i'm getting "The network connection was lost on safari" error page. (safari unable to load the page, have tried most of the workaround, clearing browser cache, cookies, disabled block cookies but no luck)

Please find the sample stackblitz of the code i've, its straight simple:

application hosted in "IIS 7". Both .aspx application and my angular application are running in same domain.

`https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4mzx6`

HTML form submission i've used:

```
<form ngNoForm method="post" action="https://test.externalwebsite/postdata/" target="_self" >
<input type="hidden" name="fieldOne" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="fieldTwo" value="608"/ >
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

anyone could you please share your inputs on this.

Comment: Can it work locally? This error will only appear when published on iis?

Comment: @samwu, locally I could not able to validate as i don't have mac pc. using google chrome "network conditions" -> by selecting "safari-ios" options, its working fine...

Comment: @samwu, thanks for the insight, from localhost its working with out any issues in safari browser all the times.. when i deploy to IIS only this is happening it seems.. (my angular app is server 1- IIS, and the redirection api which am hitting is also present in same server 1, after getting the data to redirection api, this will in-turn post to server2 (this is where problem is occuring.)

Comment: we resolved this, there is problem with the IIS server where angular is being hosted and while redirection, the connection is getting abruptly closed.